# What is JQuery/Ajax GetData url for asp.net

Tags: jquery, asp.net, ajax

Trying to learn asp.net and in a few examples I see this "GetData" url when trying to grab SQL table data.  Can someone explain where this url came from and how the examples got this url? This is in an asp.net project.

```
<script type="text/javascript">  
            $(document).ready(function () {  
                $('#dataTable').DataTable({  
                    "ajax": {  
                        "url": "/Home/GetData",  
                        "type": "GET",  
                        "datatype": "json"  
                    },  
                    "columns": [  
                        { "data": "Name" },  
                        { "data": "Position" },  
                        { "data": "Office" },  
                        { "data": "Age" },  
                        { "data": "Salary" }  
                    ]  
                });  
            });           
        </script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This url came from ASP .NET Controller, There are made HomeController where  created JsonResult function which returns Json information with GET method, There are better way to use JQuery/Ajax GetData

```js
$.ajax({
  url: '/Home/GetData',
  method: 'GET',
  data: {
    'Id': id
  },
  success: function(response) {
    $('#dataTable').html(`
        <table>
        <thead>
        <tr><th>Name</th></tr><tr><th>Position</th></tr><tr><th>Office</th></tr>
        <tr><th>Age</th></tr><tr><th>Salary</th></tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
        <tr><th>${response.Name}</th></tr><tr><th>${response.Position}</th></tr><tr><th>${response.Office}</th></tr>
        <tr><th>${response.Age}</th></tr><tr><th>${response.Salary}</th></tr>
        </tbody>
        </table>
        `);
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

i used data: {'Id': id} because when it send request to backend it need an Id of person which shold to return with special data.

and your backend GetData method looks so

```
public JsonResult GetData(int id) {
  person personIndfo = db.persons.Where(x => x.Id == id).First();


  return Json(personIndfo, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

person is a class, i created an empty class of person with personInfo name where i have inserted a person information from database which Id equals Id which i send to back.

so after if there exists a such person it will return successfully to Ajax on "success: function (response)".